# typescript: strictpropertyinitialization complains even it is initialized in costructor method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following angular component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-config',
  templateUrl: './config.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./config.component.scss']
})
export class ConfigComponent {
  value: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.init();
  }

  init(): void {
    this.value = 'abc';
  }
}
```

Even though I call the init() function in the constructor, typescript complains with the following error:

```
Property 'value' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

If i move the line

```
this.value = 'abc'
```

directly into the constructor, the error disappears.

Is this only a config thing? How can I prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does not realize you're assigning `value` a value inside another method. You'll have to put all variable init logic in the constructor.

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.value = 'abc';
}
```

or

```
value: string = 'abc'; // this results in the same javascript when compiled
```